# How can I run two SQL commands with a single connection?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

I need to insert data in one table and update id in second table using add button:

```
private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into Rent(toolId, customerId, custName, Fee, date, dueDate) Values('" + toolIdComboBx.Text + "', '" + custIdTxtBx.Text + "', '" + custNameTxtBx.Text + "', '" + feeTxtBx.Text + "', '" + dateTimePicker2.Text + "', '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "')", con);

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.Read())
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Open();

        cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Inventory Set Available = 'No' Where ToolId =  = '" + toolIdComboBx.Text + "' ");

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    con.Close();
    DisplayData();
}
```

Comment: It is always helpful if you post any errors you get or explain unexpected behaviors. Also, please format your code so that it's actually readable and for all that is holy **please** [parameterize your queries!!](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: You should only use ExecuteReader with a SELECT.  Update and Insert should both use ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish by checking the result of `dr.Read()` from an INSERT? Are you only trying to UPDATE if a row was inserted? The intent of the code isn't very clear.

Comment: Learn to parameterize your sql statements - concatenating in the manner you use is open to sql injection.

Comment: I would like to suggest using the Entity Framework. Using it you will have much more flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a few issues here

1. Always, always, always use parameterized queries (props to @broots-waymb) and never, ever concatenate user input into a SQL command
2. Use the `using` keyword to automatically clean up any object with a Dispose() method, which includes SqlConnection and SqlCommand - this ensures proper cleanup in the presence of exceptions; also it just easier to write correctly
3. Use `ExecuteNonQuery()` if you're not expecting a recordset to be returned. As @jdweng pointed out the only query that returns a recordset is a SELECT statement (stored procedures might also). The meaning of Read() is this code is unclear, my guess is that it will always return false
4. Be careful when your database schema contains one table (Inventory) whose state is dependent on the state of another table (Rent). Consider strategies to avoid this, but if you can't, then you should consider wrapping the update to both tables in a database transaction to make sure the state of your system is consistent

Answer (score 1):

You cannot close a connection if it has a open `SqlDataReader`.

Why do you read from an `INSERT` statement? What do you expect?

Also, use parameterized queries.

**Update**

There is no result value from `INSERT`, so use `ExecuteNonQuery()` instead. That way, the connection is available for the next `SqlCommand`

Comment: I want to update the Available column in the Inventory table after the insert is complete

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! I figured it out

con.Open();

```
        using (cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into Rent(toolId, customerId, custName,
```

Fee, date, dueDate) Values('" + toolIdComboBx.Text + "', '" + custIdTxtBx.Text + "', '" +

custNameTxtBx.Text + "', '" + feeTxtBx.Text + "', '" + dateTimePicker2.Text + "', '" +

dateTimePicker1.Text + "')", con))

```
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        using (cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Inventory Set Available = 'No' Where ToolId  = '" + toolIdComboBx.Text + "' ", con))

        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        };

        con.Close();

        DisplayData();
```

Comment: A word of caution on using text embedded like that. You are opening yourself for a SQL Injection attack by not using parameters. A user could enter " ' OR 1=1 " in your textbox and update all rows. The correct way to do this is to use parameters. "WHERE ToolId = @ToolId" and cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToolId", toolIdComboBx.Text)